# A string .remove error

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a program that can only store values. The way it should work is by adding a value to the start of the string and deleting the value that is situated at the end of the score.The format that I have saved the values in is 000 000 000 (Name).This is my code.

```
dim bb as string 
dim lon as string
For Each ch As Char In bb
  If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then
    lon = String.Concat(lon & ch)
  End If
Next
Select Case lon.Length
  Case Is = 9
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(c11)
    bb = ListBox1.Items(i)
    bb.Remove(8, 11)
    ListBox1.Items(i) = "00" & score & " " & bb
    If ListBox1.Items(i).Contains("0010")          Then
        bb = ListBox1.Items(i)
        bb.Replace("0010", "010")
        ListBox1.Items(i) = bb
    End If
```

The program breaks on the bb.remove(8, 10) line. Its should work but it doesnt. It comes up with a argumentoutofrangeexception error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: bb is not being set a value...have you tried putting a break point on this in in debug mode? For Each ch As Char In bb I suspect is doing nothing...

Comment: `String.Remove(8,11)` will remove 11 characters, starting from index 8. If the string contains less than 20 characters, you'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will thumbs you up when I am on a computer as the mobile phone does not allow me to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are receiving an ArgumentOutOfRangeException error. [String.Remove(int,int)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8d7z2kk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s `count` parameter specifies the number of characters to remove, not the ending index. `bb.Remove(8,10)` will remove 10 characters, starting from the 9th character. If your string contains less than 19 characters, you'll get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

If you want to remove just three characters starting from the 9th, you should use `b.Remove(8,3)`